Open new record in sub tab from highlights panel
I have a flexipage using the highlights panel component. Our users prefer this as it gives them a quick way to see opportunities onHover from the opportunity related list on a customer record. This related list contains a custom URL button called 'New Opportunity.'
/apex/LightningOutNewOpportunity?AccountId={!Account.Id}&retURL={!Account.Id}
When clicking this button from the related list that shows on hover it opens a new browser window for the new opportunity. Would like to open the new opportunity as a subtab on the open customer record.
Tried appending the button's url structure with  _self, _parent but getting same result opening opportunity in new browser tab.
clicking the New Opportunity button from View All via the onHover opportunity related list opens the opportunity in the desired sub tab. But our users will want to select this New Opportunity from the on hover list view.
Looking for some other ideas on how to do this preferably without apex, jscript, visualforce. There has to be a way to do this given we have a reference to the account id within the URL string for the New Opportunity button.
Visualforce being used:
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" showHeader="{!or($CurrentPage.parameters.id <> null,$CurrentPage.parameters.isNew=='YES')}" sidebar="{!or($CurrentPage.parameters.id <> null,$CurrentPage.parameters.isNew=='YES')}" 
       standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" >  
<head>
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.ltngOutBaseStyles}" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.ltngOutBaseScriptsV2}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/55.0/integration.js"/>
    <style>
        body.slds-scope{
        overflow-y:scroll;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="slds-scope"  onunload="CleanupOnUnLoad();">
    <div id="MENewOpportunityContainer" >
        <div id="toastMessage" />
        <div id="cmpLoad" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_medium slds-spinner_brand"><div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div><div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div></div>
    </div>
    <script>  
       
    (function(){
        let myUserContext = "{!$User.UITheme}";
        let saveClicked = false;
        let accIdJson={};           
        var urlstr='';
        accIdJson['AccountId']="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.accountId}";      
        let recordId = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}";
        let eventId  = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.eventId}";
        $Lightning.use("c:MENewOpportunityApp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:MENewOpportunityV2", {"CustomerAccId" : JSON.stringify(accIdJson),"recordId" : recordId, "UserContext": myUserContext, "eventId": eventId},"MENewOpportunityContainer",function(cmp) { 

                document.getElementById("cmpLoad").style.display = 'none';                   
                $A.eventService.addHandler({               
                    event: 'force:navigateToURL',
                    handler: function(event) { 
                        var recId = event.getParams().url;  
                        debugger;
                        if(myUserContext == 'Theme3' &&  recId!= undefined && recId != null && recId.indexOf('lightning') !=-1)   //checking url to find lightning or not
                        {                               
                            if(recId!= undefined && recId != null && recId.indexOf('https://')!=-1)
                               window.top.location.href =recId;
                            else
                            window.top.location.href = '/' + recId;
                        } 
                        else if (myUserContext == 'Theme3' && recId!= undefined && recId != null && recId.indexOf('lightning') == -1)
                            window.top.location.href = '/' + recId;
                        else
                        {  
                            //TMRTSALY-7011 - replace c.bac with bac before redirect 
                            if(recId.indexOf("c.bac.")>0){
                                recId = recId.replace('c.bac','bac');
                            } 
                            if (sforce.console.isInConsole()) {
                                 console.log('in console');
                                /* Console App Navigation : START */
                                //The callback function that closeTab will call once it has the ID for its tab
                                var callCloseTab= function callCloseTab(result) {
                                    sforce.console.closeTab(result.id);
                                }                                        
                                sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId(callCloseTab);                                                                
                                
                                sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(undefined,recId, true, '');                              
                                /* Console App Navigation : END */
                            } else {
                                console.log('in Standard Navigation');
                                window.top.location.href = recId;
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                });
                $A.eventService.addHandler({
                    event: 'force:navigateToSObject',
                    handler: function(event) {
                          debugger;
                        if (myUserContext == 'Theme3') {                               
                            var recId = event.getParams().recordId;
                                if(recId.substring(0,3) == '006') 
                                    window.parent.location.href = '/' + recId;
                            
                        }
                        else
                            {                                   
                                 var recId = event.getParams().recordId;
                                 //TMRTSALY-7011 - replace c.bac with bac before redirect 
                                 if(recId.indexOf("c.bac.")>0){
                                     recId = recId.replace('c.bac','bac');
                                 } 
                                 if(recId.substring(0,3) == '006') 
                                    window.document.URL= '/' + recId;
                                 }
                    }
                });
                
                $A.eventService.addHandler({
                    event: 'force:showToast',
                    handler: function(event) {
                        if (myUserContext == 'Theme3') {
                            var toast = event.getParams();
                            if(toast.type == 'error'){
                                showToast(toast.message);                                                           
                            }
                            else{                                                           
                                alert('Info : '+toast.message);
                                //showToast(toast.message);
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                });
                /* -- Handling Edit leave  --*/
                $A.eventService.addHandler({
                    event: 'c:ComponentUnloadEvent',
                    handler: function(event) {                            
                        if (myUserContext == 'Theme3') {
                            var params = event.getParams();
                            if(params.message === 'InEditmode'){
                                window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
                                    message = "Are you sure you want leave?";
                                    e.returnValue = message;
                                    return message;
                                };
                            }
                            else{
                                window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {};
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                });
            
            });
        }); 
    })();
    </script>
</body>

</apex:page>
